# How to display ONLY entries that have at a particular field present (like image)

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, conditionals

How can I display entries that only have a particular field completed.

In my case I am displaying all entries but would like to exclude any entries that have no image field completed. The image field is a matrix field.

Thanks
Sinan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the search parameter.

```
{exp:channel:entries search:image_custom_field_name="not IS_EMPTY" ...}
  ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This will return entries where the image custom field has been filled in.